# Single/Double side environment with different backgrounds

Tags: graphics, formatting, minipage, mdframed, backgrounds

I'm having trouble aligning some of the elements.

1. I would like align `Check Box` and `Cross Box` to be same size so that they look nicer below is what i got so far.
2. Also it would be great if they can change in size with respect to environment with (some ratio 60% of text or so)
3. Have background so that it would be easer to read.(as shown in the second part of the question)

Thank you for your help in advance!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm,showframe=false]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newsavebox\IBox
\newenvironment{good}[2][1]
{\def\scale{#1}\begin{lrbox}{\IBox}\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr#2\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}\ignorespaces}
{%
    \end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%              
    \rput( \dimexpr-10\wd\IBox+\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax,0){%               
  \scalebox{\scale}[1]{   \makebox(0,0){\put(20,0){%
 \resizebox{0.4\textwidth}{!}{\color{green!25}\Checkedbox}}}}%
        }%
    {\usebox\IBox}%
  }  
  \newenvironment{bad}[2][1]
{\def\scale{#1}\begin{lrbox}{\IBox}\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr#2\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}\ignorespaces}
{%
    \end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%              
    \rput( \dimexpr-10\wd\IBox+\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax,0){%               
  \scalebox{\scale}[1]{   \makebox(0,0){\put(20,0){%
 \resizebox{0.37\textwidth}{!}{\color{red!25}\Crossedbox}}}}%
        }%
    {\usebox\IBox}%
  }

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\vspace{3mm}

\begin{good}{0.49}
\lipsum[1]
\end{good}\hfill
\begin{bad}{0.49}
\lipsum[1]
\end{bad}

\vspace{3mm}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[UPDATE]
This is a more or less second part of the answer

I would be happy if some one can put Checked-box as the background for this one.

And again there is some aligning problems with `minipage` but i will ignore this one for now.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm,showframe=false]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{Dkgreen}{RGB}{0,135,0}

\newmdenv[
roundcorner=10pt,
middlelinecolor=red!25,
frametitlerulecolor=red!30,
frametitlerule=true,
frametitle={Example\hfill\resizebox{12pt}{!}{\color{red}\Crossedbox}}, 
frametitlebackgroundcolor=red!25,
backgroundcolor=red!8,]{test}


\newmdenv[
roundcorner=10pt,
middlelinecolor=Dkgreen!25,
frametitlerulecolor=Dkgreen!30,
frametitlerule=true,
frametitle={Example\hfill\resizebox{12pt}{!}{\color{Dkgreen}\Checkedbox}}, 
frametitlebackgroundcolor=Dkgreen!25,
backgroundcolor=Dkgreen!8,]{test2}


\begin{document}
\begin{test}

  \lipsum[1]
\end{test}

\begin{test2}

  \lipsum[1]
\end{test2}



\begin{minipage}{.48\linewidth}
  \begin{test}

  \lipsum[1]
\end{test}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.3cm}
\begin{minipage}{.48\linewidth}
\begin{test2}

  \lipsum[1]
\end{test2}
\end{minipage}%



\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you plan to add/expect floats inside two columns below checkmarks and crossmarks or is it just text ?

Comment: well it's just a text and text may be longer or shorter. I was thinking to force minimum size for checkmarks such that even if there is  one line of text, it would be forced to create space below.

Comment: Inside minipage you can't have any pagebreaks. The background can be achieved by the option `singleextra`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your are compiling with `xelatex` or `latex->ps->pdf`, because you are loading `pst-node`. If you are using `pdflatex` there is a strange interaction between `pst-node` and the option `opacity` of TikZ.

However you can add material to the background of your environment by the options `singleextra`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm,showframe=false]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definecolor{Dkgreen}{RGB}{0,135,0}

\newmdenv[
roundcorner=10pt,
middlelinecolor=red!25,
frametitlerulecolor=red!30,
frametitlerule=true,
frametitle={Example\hfill\resizebox{12pt}{!}{\color{red}\Crossedbox}}, 
frametitlebackgroundcolor=red!25,
backgroundcolor=red!8,
singleextra={%
   \path let \p1=(P) in node[opacity=.2,red,scale=10] at (.5*\x1,.5*\y1) {\Crossedbox};
 },
]{test}




\newmdenv[
roundcorner=10pt,
middlelinecolor=Dkgreen!25,
frametitlerulecolor=Dkgreen!30,
frametitlerule=true,
frametitle={Example\hfill\resizebox{12pt}{!}{\color{Dkgreen}\Checkedbox}}, 
frametitlebackgroundcolor=Dkgreen!25,
backgroundcolor=Dkgreen!8,%
singleextra={%
   \path let \p1=(P) in node[opacity=.2,Dkgreen,scale=10] at (.5*\x1,.5*\y1) {\Checkedbox};
 },
]{test2}



\begin{document}
\begin{test}

  \lipsum[1]
\end{test}

\begin{test2}

  \lipsum[1]
\end{test2}



\noindent\begin{minipage}{.48\linewidth}
  \begin{test}

  \lipsum[1]
\end{test}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}{.48\linewidth}
\begin{test2}

  \lipsum[1]
\end{test2}
\end{minipage}%



\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot :)...i'm only exploring potentials of Tex ... you must go over many packages ... *Note i think if you can add blended colours in to the mdframed it would be more powerful:) (I do like minimalism but sometimes slight change in light colours improves the look)

Comment: What do you mean with blended colors? Something like in example 7 here: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed-example-texsx.pdf

Comment: yes that exactly what i mean :) ...for some reasons ... i just like native commands more ... :)